# How to FIx this error TS2349: This expression is not callable

Tags: typescript

Code in typescript

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    event.source.postMessage("response",event.origin)
});
```

get Error at "event.origin"

```
 TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '((message: any, targetOrigin: string, transfer?: Transferable[]) => void) | { (message: any, transfer: Transferable[]): void; (message: any, options?: PostMessageOptions): void; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Can't reproduce this error in a [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQxZJW)

Comment: @TobiasS. - Your code has a `!` that the OP's code doesn't have.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - true, but the error message is still different

Comment: @TobiasS. - Good point, the first error I see is a 2531 and the second is a 2559. Neither is a 2349. Huh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the specific error you've mentioned in that code [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/O4SwdgJg9sB0CGEIFEBuBTMAXAMiAzlpugE4AUA5ALbr77wDm6FANAARnobYCUbAvAD42AbwBQbSWy6YssfFACuJAMbpYAByiEAsrXpMyAIhK0tYfOiPsZ2WFBIgG4HgG4xAXzdA), but I do see two errors, so:

1. `event.source` can be `null`, but your code assumes it isn't `null`. You have to handle that, because you can't do `null.postMessage(/*...*/)`.
2. `event.origin` is a string, but [`event.source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/source) on a `MessageEvent` (when it's not `null`) isn't necessarily a window object, so you can't assume the second parameter on `postMessage` allows a string. Sadly, `postMessage` on different objects has differing parameter lists. Window's [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#syntax) accepts a string as the second argument, but (for instance) `MessagePort`'s [doesn't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort/postMessage).

I'm going to assume since you're trying to pass a string to it, you expect `event.source` to be a window. If so, you can solve both problems with a since type guard:

```typescript
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.source instanceof Window) {
        event.source.postMessage("response", event.origin);
    }
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/O4SwdgJg9sB0CGEIFEBuBTMAXAMiAzlpugE4AUA5ALbr77wDm6FANAARnobYCUbAvAD42AbwBQbSWxAAzDl0xZY+KAFcSAY3TSwheGC1Q5AdXDRgfcVOtsF2ZWs3pYAByiEAsrXpMyAIhJaN110P3Y7JSgSEAZwHgBuCSkAXzFkhKA)

`null` never passes an `instanceof` check, so that handles both cases.